# Flutter: Multiple StreamProviders for same Class

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-provider

I am using Google cloud firestore as a backend for a flutter app. Currently I am using StreamProvider to build a stream of data from cloud firestore. Now, I need to maintain 2 separate streams but the objects in this stream have the same class type. Is there any way using Provider, where I can achieve separate streams using StreamProvider?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may need to use Multiprovider as explained [here](https://medium.com/codespace69/flutter-how-does-multiprovider-work-with-providers-of-the-same-type-bd632bd2cbad)